# Understand assembly code in a C function on x86

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

Let's say I have a C function:

```
char* func(char* cp1, int i1, char* cp2, int* ip1);
```

Questions:

1. the address cp1 pointing is passed in in RDI, value of i1 in RSI, address cp2 pointing in RDX, and address of ip1 in RCX?
2. if it is true that RDX holds the address cp2 pointing, then what does `movzx  edx,BYTE PTR [rdi+0x3]` do?  As EDX is just the lower 32 bit of RDX, which holds a memory address.
3. is the returned char pointer stored in RAX?

Trying to understand the function call convention on x86.

Thanks.

======

To provide more details:

```
// here is the caller's code
int some_int = 1;
// ptr2 is char[55]
func(ptr1, 88, ptr2, &some_int);
```

The assembly code is generated by gcc (I believe as vendor does code injection) for x86_64 on Linux (e.g. CentOS 7).

Here is the assembly code

```
                   .data:00000000 83 fe 03                         cmp    $0x3,%esi
                   .data:00000003 7e 3b                            jle    0x00000040
                   .data:00000005 83 ee 04                         sub    $0x4,%esi
                   .data:00000008 c1 ee 02                         shr    $0x2,%esi
                   .data:0000000b 48 8d 44 b7 04                   lea    0x4(%rdi,%rsi,4),%rax
                   .data:00000010 eb 16                            jmp    0x00000028
                   .data:00000012 66 0f 1f 44 00 00                nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
                   .data:00000018 0f b6 57 03                      movzbl 0x3(%rdi),%edx
                   .data:0000001c 30 57 02                         xor    %dl,0x2(%rdi)
                   .data:0000001f 48 83 c7 04                      add    $0x4,%rdi
                   .data:00000023 48 39 c7                         cmp    %rax,%rdi
                   .data:00000026 74 18                            je     0x00000040
                   .data:00000028 0f b6 4f 01                      movzbl 0x1(%rdi),%ecx
                   .data:0000002c 38 0f                            cmp    %cl,(%rdi)
                   .data:0000002e 77 e8                            ja     0x00000018
                   .data:00000030 0f b6 57 02                      movzbl 0x2(%rdi),%edx
                   .data:00000034 30 57 03                         xor    %dl,0x3(%rdi)
                   .data:00000037 48 83 c7 04                      add    $0x4,%rdi
                   .data:0000003b 48 39 c7                         cmp    %rax,%rdi
                   .data:0000003e 75 e8                            jne    0x00000028
                   .data:00000040 31 c0                            xor    %eax,%eax
                   .data:00000042 c3                               retq
```

Comment: (1) yes. (2) this overwrites `edx` (and thus, the lower half of `rdx`) with `cp1[3]`. (3) yes.

Comment: The C language specification leaves those details to implementations, and implementations vary in how they do it.  More so on x86 than on x86_64, and much more so on Windows than on Linux and other Unix-y operating systems, but you'll need to be rather more specific to get a (correct) specific answer.

Comment: The real answers are: (1) yes, if and only if your compiler follows the System V AMD64 ABI calling convention, which should be true for basically every x86-64 Linux compiler; (2) impossible to answer without looking at the full assembly code of the function, you should add that in your question if you want a correct answer; (3) again, most likely yes, but depends on the ABI.

Comment: @fuz I just added the caller's code.  Isn't it weird that `movzx  edx,BYTE PTR [rdi+0x3]` tries to change the address that `cp2` point 2? as `cp2` is holding a valid memory address.

Comment: @HCSF that doesn't add any information to answer point 2. You should add *the assembly code* of the `func()` function.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli just added.  thanks :)

Comment: You should also post C source of `func` if available. As far as I can tell, it's not using the `cp2` argument at all, which is why the code overwrites `rdx`.

Comment: Wikipedia has this handy table near the end of this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions .   You are looking for the System V ABI or GCC.

Comment: @Jester I don't have the source code of `func`.

Comment: @Jester I agree with you that it seems like none of the bytes of `EDX` is really used.  It is odd to me such asm code would be generated.  I am fairly sure the vendor doesn't write the asm code but the C code (of `func()`) and has a compiler generated the asm code (above).

Comment: As I said, that can happen if the C code doesn't use that argument. It may be there for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @Jester so you mean even if the C code doesn't use that argument, the assembly code could still do something random with the argument like `movzx edx,BYTE PTR [rdi+0x3]`?

Comment: Argument registers are normal caller-saved general purpose registers. The function may use them for whatever it wants.

Comment: Right, just seems odd that a compiler generated something like `movzx edx,BYTE PTR [rdi+0x3]` that has no purpose at all.

Comment: That **does** have a purpose (although it wouldn't need to be a `movzx`). The next line uses `dl` in a `xor` and that is the low byte of `edx`.

Comment: @Jester good catch.  thanks!